# How can I utilize the 'import xml file' functionality found on the Generic Iinquiry (among some others) screen?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have BLC code where I want to obtain a file and use its contents - similar to how the Generic Inquiry screen pops up a dialog to import a previous exported XML file:

[image]

Bottom line:  I want to import an XML (or any other type of) file using the dialog box.

I can't find anything in the aspx in GI for this dialog box, and the source code for the GI screen just shows blank / nothing.

Any examples out there I can use?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `PXUploadDialog` to you `ASPX` file and use it as a smart panel.

You can find more details here: https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/03/process-file-in-memory.html

Comment: Much obliged - thanks!! ;D